# How is Date class implemented in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

1. Date() -> date string
2. new Date() -> returns the date object.

Can anyone help me with the actual implementation of Date() **not new Date()**, new Date() implementations can be simply a class.

is it the same class, if yes then We can not instantiate a class without new then how Date() returns a string?

Comment: This should be helpful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/285154/why-can-a-constructor-be-used-without-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: This is described in the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#return_value

Comment: @JSONDerulo I know that it can be called as a function and return a string. I was curious about its actual implementation.

Comment: Implementations are generally engine specific. Which engine’s implementation are you interested in learning about? What results has inspecting the relevant source code of that engine yielded you thus far?

Comment: A function can tell if it is being invoked as a constructor and when it is not. There's nothing stopping a constructor from detecting when it is invoked as a plain function, and then using its features as a class to create a new instance and use it to create a return value.

Comment: @esqew V8 or any, was curious about the implementation of built-in objects. Can we create that kind of object (instantiable and callable)?

Comment: @Pointy could you please explain with the help of Date() and new Date()

Comment: When the Date function detects that it has been called as a plain function, it can `return new Date().toString();`

Comment: @MisterJojo That's correct. I know that but my question was how it can be implemented?

Comment: Have fun. https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/main/src/builtins/builtins-date.cc

Comment: @Pointy Got it. Thanks. We can check with new.target or this.constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a constructor called "Something", and you want it to work kind-of like the Date constructor, you can do something like this:

```
function Something(... args) {
  if (this == null || !(this instanceof Something)) {
    return new Something(... args).toString();
  }

  // normal constructor initialization code
}
```

The `if` statement checks to see if `this` has been bound to an instance of `Something`, which will be true if the function is invoked with `new`. (There may be more "bullet-proof" ways of making that test; this example is probably fine for most purposes.)

If the `if` test decides that `Something()` has *not* been invoked as a constructor, it can do whatever it wants: throw an exception, re-invoke itself *with* `new`, or, as in the example, make an instance and use it to return a value other than a new initialized instance.